# an appendFile function for non-string inputs

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming, monads

I want to write a file consisting of a list of tuples, but `appendFile` demands string inputs. I imagine I could just `show` or quote the tuples to stringify them and `read` them later; however, I'd like to just be able to save the list of n-tuples to skip the "`show` now and `read` later" part. Is there a `Show a=>FilePath -> a -> IO ()` version of the `appendFile` function?

Comment: You can try searching for your type signature on Hoogle: http://haskell.org/hoogle

Comment: The signature you suggest implies `show` will be called anyway. Hence I can't understand the purpose of doing this. Did you, perhaps, want to save your data in a binary format instead?

Answer (score 2):

A [quick hoogle search](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Show+a+%3D%3E+FilePath+-%3E+a+-%3E+IO+%28%29) reveals that there isn't a function with type [`Show a => FilePath -> a -> IO ()`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Show+a+%3D%3E+FilePath+-%3E+a+-%3E+IO+%28%29). However, it's not really hard to write it yourself:

```
showAppendFile :: Show a => FilePath -> a -> IO ()
showAppendFile p x = appendFile p (show x)
```

Comment: I'd mentioned this "solution" already. The problem with this is you end up with a file of Strings, not bare tuples. The reason for overloading the function with the class constraint is because in order to read from the file I figured it must be a showable type. That's probably more so just because of the file format I'd not thought too hard about choosing carefully.